# K&R 2.6 Exercise setbits(x,p,n,y) function

Tags: c, bitwise

> Write a function `setbits(x,p,n,y)` that returns `x` with the `n` bits that begin at position `p` set to the rightmost `n` bits of `y`, leaving the other bits unchanged.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n,unsigned y);

int main(void){
    unsigned result=setbits(0, 4, 3, ~0);
    printf("%d\n",result);
    return 0;
}


unsigned setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n,unsigned y){
    unsigned ybits = y & ~(~0 << n);
    unsigned helper = ~(~0 << n);
    unsigned result = (x | (helper << (p+1-n))) & ((ybits << (p+1-n)) | (~(helper << (p+1-n))));
    return result;
}
```

Output:

> 28

Comment: Are the 3 bits that start at bit 4 bits 4,5,6 or bits 4,3,2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example, which uses `x = 0` and `y = ~0`, is not a very useful demonstration, as those degenerate cases would tend to let bugs remain undetected.

---

You have some common expressions that reappear several times, which should be given variable names:

- `(p+1-n)` appears three times in `result`.  I would name it `shift`.
- `~(~0 << n)` appears in `ybits`, but it is the same as `helper`.  I would name it `mask`.

  I would write it as `(1 << n) - 1` instead.  It's probably not any more or less efficient than `~(~0 << n)`.  However, you use bitwise negation a lot.  When you write `(~(helper << (p+1-n)))`, that's a negation of a negation of a negation, which I find headache-inducing.

Conversely, you gave variable names to `ybits` and `result`, neither of which provide any benefit.

---

Your strategy is, in summary:

> ```
> (x | ForceRelevantBitsOn) & ((ybits << ShiftToRelevantPlace) | OnesEverywhereElse)
> ```

However, that strategy requires you to construct `OnesEverywhereElse`.  I recommend the following simpler technique instead:

```
(x & ForceRelevantBitsOff) | (ybits << ShiftToRelevantPlace)
```

---

Here's how I would write it:

```
unsigned setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y) {
    int shift = p - n + 1;
    unsigned mask = (1 << n) - 1;
    return (x & ~(mask << shift)) | ((y & mask) << shift);
}
```

The last line could be replaced with this expression, which might be more efficient (using five operations instead of six), but is more cryptic:

```
    return ((((x >> shift) ^ y) & mask) << shift) ^ x;
```

That works by determining which bits in `x` need to be toggled.

Comment: Nice improvement.Just there is a part i do not understand.You said that `~(~0 << n)` is equal to `(1 << n) - 1` but why ? Firstly 1 is not equal to ~0 right ? And secondly why do you substract it from 1 ?